# Building unity ios, I have no dependencies in ios, only on Android, when ios is built, it's successful, but no podfile or workspace are generayed

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, podfile

Unity 2022.3.40, building ios project is successful with no errors or warnings, but podfile or workspace are not generated, all the settings are already set to make xcode workspace.

How I solved: grab a podfile (and podfile.lock) from other project, delete all the dependencies from it, open terminal on the xcode project, and do "pod install", this will generate the workspace.

Just wondering if there is a better way

Tried to build ios xcode workspace.
Expected a workspace and podfile to be created.